# Why doesn't my C program print the correct string?

Tags: c

I am writing a simple C program which reverses a string, taking the string from `argv[1]`. Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* flip_string(char *string){
  int i = strlen(string);
  int j = 0;
  // Doesn't really matter all I wanted was the same size string for temp.
  char* temp = string; 
  puts("This is the original string");
  puts(string);
  puts("This is the \"temp\" string");
  puts(temp);

  for(i; i>=0; i--){
    temp[j] = string[i]
    if (j <= strlen(string)) {
      j++;
    }
  }

  return(temp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  puts(flip_string(argv[1]));
  printf("This is the end of the program\n");
}
```

That's basically it, the program compiles and everything but does not return the `temp` string in the end (just blank space). In the beginning it prints `temp` fine when it's equal to `string`. Furthermore if I do a character by character `printf` of `temp` in the `for` loop, the correct `temp` string in printed i.e. string -> reversed. just when I try to print it to standard out (after the `for` loop/ or in the `main`) nothing happens - only blank space is printed.

Comment: Just a reminder for the close-happy bandits: development is on-topic here.

Comment: Looks like a generic programming question better suited for SO.

Comment: @Oli I know, but that's way too generic, and the close reason includes "generic programming questions on Stack Overflow.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems in your code, first you just define a pointer to your already existing string. So while you write the `temp` string you overwrite the input string. So create a new string.

The second problem is that the string ends with a `0` to signal the end of the string. So if you write the last character at the beginning of the new string it will end at the very first character. So your reverted string will not be seen.

The following changes to your function worked for me:

```c
char* flip_string(char *string){
  int i = strlen(string);
  int j = 0;
  // Doesn't really matter all I wanted was the same size string for temp.
  char* temp = malloc(strlen(string)); 
  puts("This is the original string");
  puts(string);
  puts("This is the \"temp\" string");
  puts(temp);
    i--;
  for(i; i>=0; i--){
    temp[j] = string[i];
    if (j <= strlen(string)) {
      j++;
    }
  }

  return(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, One last question though on your second point. In an test run, I entered "1234" as my string when I printed out the length of the string it said 4( which is what I wanted) so how is it going to terminate at the null character upon printing as the 4th character in the string is going to be "1" right not the null terminator right?